STM32SD library DMA integration for STM32H743 in platformio
I am working on a project to play a video from raw images from an SD card using SDIO, but I am having issues with the code as it takes more time so I am not getting the required 30-40fps. I tried to integrate DMA into the library files I took help from another code generated by stm32cubeide but the code gets stuck at the beginning. I think I have done something wrong with the integration. I modified the bsp_sd and sd_diskio files but it did not work for me.
STM32SD Library
